# How do you change the selected option in a select menu by the value in Jquery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, cordova, select, jquery-mobile

I need to change the selected option with the value coming from the database.

Here is the code:

```
// this code is in ondeviceready function.
 function onDeviceReady() {
     $("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).selectmenu("refresh");
 }
```

This code is in somewhere in div

```
<div>
    <select name="txtgender2" id="txtgender2" data-role="slider">
        <option value="Male" >Male</option>
        <option value="Female">Female</option>
    </select> 
</div>
```

How do I change the selected option of the `selectmenu`?

Comment: Did you check if onDeviceReady() was properly called ? and that 'data.data.gender' had a proper value ?

Comment: Well i finally solved it, if you want to refresh the select menu with data-role slider you have to use
$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).slider("refresh");
instead of
$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).selectmenu("refresh");

Comment: Add it as answer to your question, not in comments.

Comment: just a suggestion, you should create an answer for your own question, there is an option for answering your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh the select menu with data-role slider you have to use:

```
$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).slider("refresh"); 
instead of:

$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).selectmenu("refresh");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh the select menu with `data-role` slider you have to use:

```
$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).slider("refresh");
```

instead of:

```
$("#txtgender2").val(data.data.gender).selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: Original answer posted by @user1733984

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#txtgender2 option[value="'+data.data.gender+'"]").attr('selected', 'selected');  
$('#txtgender2').selectmenu('refresh');
```